# Finding the value of a constant from a density function

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, median

[image: link to question]

I was wondering if someone could help me here. I think I start by integrating the density function and sub in M and then let it equal the equation equal to 0.5 as its the median but I don't know if this is correct or how to actually do this.

Comment: Yes.  Find the cumulative distribution function by integration, set it equal to $0.5$ for the median, and solve for $b$

Comment: So does this mean when I integrate I should get X^(b) =0.5 and the. Sub in M to get 0.4^(b)=0.5 and then solve for b?

Comment: Should get what??

Comment: So does this mean when I integrate I should get X^(b) =0.5 and then sub in M=0.4 to get 0.4^(b)=0.5 and then solve for b?

Comment: yes ${0.4}^b = 0.5$

Comment: Thank you so the final answer should just be ln(0.5)/ln(0.4) which is roughly 0.75647...

Comment: yes till $3$ decimal point :)